# Make Pretty URLS with htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I made a php mvc for a school project, and I've never used htaccess before but I want to make my URLs look pretty...

Right now the URL's are `/?controller=posts&action=index` but I would like to have them show as `posts/index` which is `Controller/Action`.. I also have a folder called "assets" with has my css files and images.

Is this possible to do without breaking my assets folder and site?

Thanks :)

EDIT:

I tried the following code but if I go to `/posts/index` it shows the homepage & if I go to `/?controller=posts&action=index` it doesn't change the name or anything

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?controller=$1&action=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 rules to accomplish the entire requirements and use conditions to ignore real files and directories.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /\?controller=([^\s&]+)&action=([^\s&]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?controller=$1&action=$2 [L,QSA]
```

This will also most likely cause css to not load so you also need this in the `head` section of your html.

```
<base href="http://www.yoursite.com" />
```